# Multiple register in one get_pin in xdc

Tags: verilog, xilinx, vivado

I am using Vivado 2016.4.

My design failed timing and I want to set the paths as false paths. The problem is that Vivado is showing me paths between single bits between two registers, and when I want to set it as a false path, I can only set false paths between said two single bits, like so

```
set_false_path -from [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/current_sample_reg[8]/C}] -to [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/address_read_reg[0]/S}]
set_false_path -from [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/current_sample_reg[8]/C}] -to [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/address_read_reg[3]/R}]
set_false_path -from [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/current_sample_reg[8]/C}] -to [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/address_read_reg[8]/R}]
set_false_path -from [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/current_sample_reg[8]/C}] -to [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/address_read_reg[9]/R}]
set_false_path -from [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/current_sample_reg[8]/C}] -to [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/address_read_reg[1]/R}]
set_false_path -from [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/current_sample_reg[8]/C}] -to [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/address_read_reg[5]/R}]
set_false_path -from [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/current_sample_reg[8]/C}] -to [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/address_read_reg[6]/R}]
set_false_path -from [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/current_sample_reg[8]/C}] -to [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/address_read_reg[7]/R}]
set_false_path -from [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/current_sample_reg[8]/C}] -to [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/address_read_reg[10]/R}]
set_false_path -from [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/current_sample_reg[8]/C}] -to [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/address_read_reg[11]/R}]
```

Now, I is there a way set a false path in one line for all the bits between these two registers, something like

```
set_false_path -from [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/current_sample_reg[8:0]/C}] -to [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/address_read_reg[11:0]/R}]
```

Bonus question: What is the /C and /R at the end of the name of the registers?

Comment: Read the Xilinx constraints guide. In many examples they use wildcards (*).

Comment: @Oldfart so you mean that I would write set_false_path -from [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/current_sample_reg[\wildcard]/C}] -to [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/address_read_reg[\wildcard]/R}] (instead of \wildcard read asterix)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you can use a wildcard instead of a number to catch all the bits

```
 set_false_path -from [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/current_sample_reg[*]/C}] -to [get_pins {bram_controller_y_TV/address_read_reg[*]/R}]
```

Bonus Answer: Vivado synthesizes primitives like flip flops. The C is the clock input of the ff, S and R are inputs of an SR FF